# How to format Time and String value in Java's String formatter

Tags: java

Using Java String.format() how do I format a string to result in "Time - userId" (ie. 3:02 pm - joe user).

I have worked several iterations, and I think it is the space between the minutes and the am/pm that is throwing me off.  My last iteration is

```
String.format("%1$tl:%1$tM %1$tp - %2s", new Date(), "joe user");
```

I am about to punt and use a SimpleDateFormat, but thought I would ask here first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `%2$s` to get the second argument, as shown below:

```
String.format("%1$tl:%1$tM %1$tp - %2$s", new Date(), "joe user")
```

prints:

```
4:56 pm - joe user
```